# .NET Regex Replace Single Line Matching Unknown Character

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

This has me extremely baffled. Why am I getting duplicate replace strings in the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String input = "test";
    String pattern = ".*";
    String replacement = "replace";
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement));
    Console.Read();
}
```

This outputs to the console:

```
replacereplace
```

I understand that regex gets weird matching end line characters but there should be none. I also understand that the pattern can match nothing, but clearly the input is not nothing. This happens in .Net 3.5 and 4.0 and I get the same thing with SingleLine and MultiLine.

I know there are several alternatives that will do what I'm expecting but I'm wondering more about what other match .* thinks its finding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get two replacements is because with `.*` you get two matches: `"test"`, and `""`.

If you change `.*` to `.+` it will work the way you expect it to:

```
String pattern = ".+";
```

Another option is to add the start of string anchor:

```
String pattern = "^.*"; // I know this looks like a smiley
```

Comment: You got me in the finishing line :)

Comment: I agree, this does fix it but I was looking for the why.

Comment: The Chrome app "Regex Tester App" shows the same behaviour, until you check the global flag. I just wish that .Net could implement this flag too...

Answer (score 2):

It matches nothing and then it matches everything therefore you have two matches and two replaces.

Comment: Stupid nothing. And why have I never run into this before.

Comment: @JoshuaBelden maybe you did run to it but you never discovered it :)